# Compartir variable en controlador Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy realizando un intranet para mi trabajo, es un control de producción (Somos una imprenta, la plataforma es para saber en que departamento está cada trabajo en cada momento). La plataforma consta de diferentes fases (departamentos), trabajos, clientes y trabajadores.

Hasta ahí todo bien.

En el apartado ver fase, muestro el total de trabajos que se encuentran en esa fase, con la siguiente función:

```
public function numberOfWorksForCategories($faseToShow)
{
    $count = count($faseToShow->works);
    foreach ($faseToShow->fases as $fase){
        foreach($fase->works as $work){
            $count = $count + count($work);
        }
    }

    return $count;
}
```

la función que muestra el view es la siguiente:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $fases = Fase::orderBy("orden")->get();
    $faseToShow = Fase::find($id);
    $idFase = $this->idFase;
    $totalFases = $this->numberOfWorksForCategories($faseToShow);
    $orderType = Input::get("orderType");
    $orderBy = Input::get("orderBy");
    if (!$orderType) {
        $orderType = "desc";
    }
    if (!$orderBy) {
        $orderBy = "id";
    }
    return view("fase", compact("fases", "faseToShow", "orderBy", "orderType", "totalFases","totaltoShow","totalWorks"));
}
```

El problema que tengo es el siguiente. En el código arriba mostrado obtengo la id de la fase via GET, pero en el lado izquierdo de la página tengo una lista donde aparecen las fases (tipo menú), y me gustaría que apareciera el total de trabajos en cada una de las fases.

Entonces, según mi lógica he realizado los siguiente: 
- He creado una función similar a la anterior mostrada

```
protected $idFase;
public function numberOfWorksLeft($idFase){
    $this->idFase =$idFase;
   $count = count($idFase->works);
    foreach ($idFase->fases as $fase){
        foreach ($fase->works as $work){
            $count = $count + count($work);
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
```

esa id fase se la paso por el template:

```
@foreach($fases as $fase)
        <li class="mb-1" title="{{ $fase->descripcion }}"><a
                href="{{ route("fase", $fase->id) }}">{{ $fase->nombre  }}</a> <small>({{$TotalLeft($fase->id)}} Jobs)</small></li>
        @if(count($fase->fases) > 0)
            @foreach($fase->fases->sortBy('orden') as $fase2)
                <li class="mb-1 second-level" title="{{ $fase2->descripcion }}">> <a
                            href="{{ route("fase", $fase2->id) }}">{{ $fase2->nombre  }}</a></li>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

y en el show incluyo la variable del view:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $fases = Fase::orderBy("orden")->get();
    $faseToShow = Fase::find($id);
    $idFase = $this->idFase;
    $TotalLeft = $this->numberOfWorksLeft($idFase);
    $totalFases = $this->numberOfWorksForCategories($faseToShow);
    $orderType = Input::get("orderType");
    $orderBy = Input::get("orderBy");
    if (!$orderType) {
        $orderType = "desc";
    }
    if (!$orderBy) {
        $orderBy = "id";
    }
    return view("fase", compact("fases", "faseToShow",'TotalLeft', "orderBy", "orderType", "totalFases","totaltoShow","totalWorks"));
}
```

Me da error "Undefined variable: TotalLeft"

¿Qué hago mal?

Comment: ¿Por qué `TotalLeft` es la única que tiene comillas simples?, aunque no creo que sea el error...

Comment: No, no es el error, se me ha colado :)

Comment: ¿El error te lo da en la vista o en el controlador?

Comment: Al hacer login, no carga la vista.